# Awk print specific lines where a column has a max value greater than 0.5

Tags: awk

I have a tab delimited file that looks like this with 5 columns.

```
temp1   56   09   34,54,65,6   file1
temp2   45   23   4,55,11,7,8,4,7   file2
temp3   123  56   0.01,0,50,4,4,4,6,7,1,3,44,67,8  file3
temp4   11   56   0.006,0.006,0.006  file4
temp5   10   123  0.00001,0.005,0.004 file5
```

I would like to be able to split column 4, and look at each value in the list and if the max value from that list in col 4 is greater than 0.5 then print out the whole line.

So the output would be:

```
temp1   56   09   34,54,65,6   file1
temp2   45   23   4,55,11,7,8,4,7   file2
temp3   123  56   0.01,0,50,4,4,4,6,7,1,3,44,67,8  file3
```

This is what I have attempted so far:

```
cat inputFile.txt|awk 'BEGIN {FS="\t"}; NR>1 {print $4}'|awk '{split($1,a,","); if (max(a)>0.5) print $0}'
```

But i have become to confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please try following.

```
awk '
{
  num=split($4,array,",")
  for(i=1;i<=num;i++){
    max=max>array[i]?max:array[i]
  }
  if(max>0.5){
    print
  }
  max=""
}
' Input_file
```

You need not to use `cat` with an `awk` solution as `awk` could read Input_file by itself.

***Explanation:*** Adding explanation for above code.

```
awk '                                   ##Starting awk program here.
{
  num=split($4,array,",")               ##Splitting 4th column into an array named array with delimiter of comma here.
  for(i=1;i<=num;i++){                  ##Starting a for loop from i=1 till value of num(which is total number of elements after we split 4th column with delimiter comma).
    max=max>array[i]?max:array[i]       ##Creating a variable named max whose value is max or array with index i whichever is greater each time cursor comes here.
  }
  if(max>0.5){                          ##Checking condition here if max variable is grater than 0.5 as per OP need then do following.
    print                               ##Printing current line.
  }
  max=""                                ##Nullifying max variable value so that next cycle it should not take previous values.
}
' Input_file                            ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Comment: Hi. I need it for all values in column 4, so some rows have 10 comma separated values, others have 3 and others can have 2.

I need the max value from the list.

Comment: @Rk_23, Ok sure, please check my update and lemme know on same then?

Comment: No need to use `FS="\t"`.  Any space/tab is the default behaviour of `awk`, so first solution would work if its space, multiple space or tab.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 Thank you heaps. This solution lead us into the right direction and answered my query! Thanks heaps!

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS="\t"; tgt=0.5 }
{
    split($4,vals,/,/)
    max = vals[1]
    for (i in vals) {
        max = (vals[i] > max ? vals[i] : max)
    }
}
max > tgt

$ awk -f tst.awk file
temp1   56      09      34,54,65,6      file1
temp2   45      23      4,55,11,7,8,4,7 file2
temp3   123     56      0.01,0,50,4,4,4,6,7,1,3,44,67,8 file3
```